# Method conflicts with Method from Superclass - Override gives error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've got the `class Menu: SKScene`, then a `func touchesBegan` inside of it which gives me the error of:

> Method 'touchesBegan(*:withEvent:)' with Objective-C selector 'touchesBegan:withEvent:' conflicts with method 'touchesBegan(*:withEvent:)' from superclass 'UIResponder' with the same Objective-C selector

Anyway, if I add override in front of the function it says:

> Method does not override any method from its superclass.

Any idea? The whole code:

```
import SpriteKit

class Menu: SKScene {




var title : SKLabelNode?
var start : SKLabelNode?

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    self.title = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
    self.start = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")

    self.title!.name = "title"
    self.start!.name = "new"


    self.addChild(self.title!)
    self.addChild(self.start!)
}

    func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent even: UIEvent) {

        self.menuHelper(touches)
    }

    func menuHelper(touches: NSSet) {
        for touch in touches {
            let nodeAtTouch = self.nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self))
            if nodeAtTouch.name == "title" {
                print("Title pressed")
            }
            else if nodeAtTouch.name == "new" {
                print("Start pressed")
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature (from the docs) for this method is...

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
```

`touches` is a `Set` (not `NSSet`) of `UITouch` objects and `event` is an optional `UIEvent`.

You also need to override it...

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.menuHelper(touches)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Still learning the basics.